# How to create a generic Partial View in MVC5

Tags: razor, view, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

I have a question about creating a generic Partial View in MVC5.

I have multiple views which have below htmlhelpers (I only display one helper to simplify the question) :

```
View 1 :
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category.Img, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "a" })
View 2 :
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Car.ImgOne, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "a" })
```

Is it possible to create a partial view that can be used in both views ?

The call for View1 to the partial view would be f.e. :

```
@Html.Partial("_MyLabelPartial", new {
    _var1 = "Category",
    _var2 = "ImgOne"
}.ToViewDataDictionary())
```

The call for View2 to the partial view would be f.e. :

```
@Html.Partial("_MyLabelPartial", new {
    _var1 = "Car",
    _var2 = "Img"
}.ToViewDataDictionary())
```

But how should my partial view look ? I tried :

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.@ViewBag._var1.@ViewBag._var2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, in short. A partial is just like any other Razor view in that you can pass a model instance into it.

Comment: Thanks ... Yes, I know ... but I don't see how that solves my question.

Comment: You’ve kind of answered it yourself with those two partials.

Comment: The problem is how to code the partial (see edit just made).